# Video size increase after using video compressor flutter package?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

I am using the Flutter package video_compress to compress videos in Flutter. However, the size of videos increases after compression. Some videos compress and some video's size increases after compression. I don't know why the Flutter package behaves like this My complete code is attached. I would be glad if someone could help:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({super.key});

@override
State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
File? fileVideo;
Uint8List? thumbnailBytes;
int? videoSize;
MediaInfo? CompressedVideoInfo;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

  body: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
    child: buildContent(),
  ),
 );
}
Widget buildContent() {
 if (fileVideo == null) {
  return ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: pickVideo,
    child: Text("Pick Video"),
  );
} else {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      buildThumbnail(),
      SizedBox(height: 24),
      buildVideoInfo(),
      SizedBox(height: 24),
      buildVideoCompressedInfo(),
      SizedBox(height: 24),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: compressVideo,
        child: Text("Compress"),
      )
    ],
  );
 }
 }

 Future pickVideo() async {
final picker = ImagePicker();
final pickedFile = await picker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

if (pickedFile == null) return;

final file = File(pickedFile.path);

setState(() {
  fileVideo = file;
});

 generateThumbnail(fileVideo!);

 getVideoSize(fileVideo!);
}

 Future generateThumbnail(File file) async {
final thumbytes = await VideoCompress.getByteThumbnail(file.path);

setState(() {
  thumbnailBytes = thumbytes;
});
 }

 Future getVideoSize(File file) async {
 final size = await file.length();

 setState(() {
  videoSize = size;
 });
}

 Widget buildThumbnail() => thumbnailBytes == null
  ? CircularProgressIndicator()
  : Image.memory(thumbnailBytes!, height: 100);

 Widget buildVideoInfo() {
 if (videoSize == null) return Container();

final size = videoSize! / 1000;

return Column(
  children: [
    Text('Original Video Info'),
    SizedBox(height: 8),
    Text('Size: $size KB'),
  ],
);
 }

  Future compressVideo() async {
  showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (context) => Dialog(
    child: ProgressDialogWidget(),
  ),
);

final info = await VideoCompressApi.compressVideo(fileVideo!);

setState(() {
  CompressedVideoInfo = info;
});
Navigator.of(context).pop();
 }

  Widget buildVideoCompressedInfo() {
  if (CompressedVideoInfo == null) return Container();

  final size = CompressedVideoInfo!.filesize! / 1000;

   return Column(
  children: [
    Text('Compressed Video Info'),
    SizedBox(
      height: 8,
    ),
    Text('Size: $size KB'),
    SizedBox(
      height: 8,
    ),
     Center(child: Text('${CompressedVideoInfo!.path}')),
   ],
  );
}

 void clearSelection() => setState(() {
    CompressedVideoInfo = null;
    fileVideo = null;
  });
}

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 class VideoCompressApi {
 static Future<MediaInfo?> compressVideo(File file) async {
 try {
  await VideoCompress.setLogLevel(0);

  return VideoCompress.compressVideo(
    file.path,
    quality: VideoQuality.Res640x480Quality,
    includeAudio: true,
  );
  } catch (e) {
  VideoCompress.cancelCompression();
 }
 }
 }
```